# How to use Apartment gem in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Apartment gem is not working in Rails 6 and Rails 7 projects - it failes on undefined method `new' for "Apartment::Reloader.

Is there good way howto solve this problem? Or is there any good replacement of this gem? We need it for a new big project...

Comment: This straddles the line on recommendation questions -- there are branches for the apartment gem that support rails 6 and 7 -- best bet might be give one of them a shot.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, the **apartment gem** is no longer actively maintained by its owners and therefore has been forked into what is now known as **ros-apartment** gem. It works with Rails 6 as I have used it but yet try with Rails 7.

You can also use **act_as_tenant gem** which works fine with Rails 6 and 7.

The difference between the two is that *ros-apartment* uses a schema or database (depending on the database type) approach while *act_as_tenant* uses a row base.

The links below are the documentation sources for the gems

1. [ros-apartment](https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment)
2. [act_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant)

Answer (score 2):

While SO is not the ideal platform for recommendations, I often find ruby-toolbox to be a good source:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the Apartment gem if working with rails 6/7 to implement multitenancy at the db level. Rails natively supports connection switching that can be used to implement this. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html. If you want table level tenancy, then I believe acts_as_tenant works for this.

I have implemented the former on a project.

Comment: Consider that the current rails multi databases config is meant to have read/write replicas instead of dealing with multi-tenants. (which you can do btw, but the API is not the best for that job)

Some Multi-tenancy Gems implements different strategies, like using schemas (postgres) or differents DB's, there are different pros and const in each one. Active Record multi db still lack a lot of functionalities :(

https://blog.arkency.com/comparison-of-approaches-to-multitenancy-in-rails-apps/

This article has great info about each approach

Comment: @lcjury I'm aware of the pros and cons...spent a ridiculous amount of time on this. My answer is good for db-level tenancy. For table level, acts_as_tenant is a good choice. For schema-level switching (which I had before), you can use the apartment gem or its forks. But the authors of the gem are not actively supporting it and also wrote an article discouraging its use. The rails db switching provides low level db switching interface which you can use for read/write replicas and much more!! See https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/12/02/building-a-multi-tenant-ruby-on-rails-app-with-subdomains.html